# Set 2 different colors in a Button

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have a simple app with jokes. There are buttons where I set the text with this code:

```
bt_barjokes.setText(getString(R.string.bar_jokes)+ " ("+barjokes.size()+")");
```

Works perfectly and it gives the correct title and size of the used Arraylist: Bar Jokes (55)

The problem is I want to change the color and font size of (55):

```
("+barjokes.size()+")")
```

I have tried several of the suggested solutions in this forum but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ForegroundColorSpan` to change text color, and `AbsoluteSizeSpan` or `RelativeSizeSpan` to change font size.

Answer (score 2):

You can look @xizzhu 's answer, its ok additionally you can use  `SpannableString` or `Html.fromHtml`

```
setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#343434>" +"<small>"+ "Little Black Text" +"</small>"+
"</font>"+"&nbsp&nbsp"+"<font color=#123456>" +"<big>" +"Big Blue Text" +"</big>"+ "</font>"));
```

**@Edit** : If you wanna use this in your button  add this line in xml like: `android:textAllCaps="false"`

You can use : `<small>` or `<big>` , tested in `Toolbar`:

[image]

and in `Button`, its looking like :

[image]

Comment: I tried adding the code, but the button text dont change. I tried testing with your exact code, but it only writes the text (Little Black Text Big Blue Text) with a normal black font. No blue color or larger font.

Comment: @FlemmingWacherDanielsen my friend i've edited my answer for you please check Edit section